# JavaScript & copy style

Tags: javascript, css

I am copying a table cell with javascript.

It works fine, just that it doesn't copy the style.
I wanted to copy like below, but that didn't work.
newCell.style=oldCell.style;

So I figured that for my text-align, I have to copy it like this:
newCell.style.textAlign=oldCell.style.textAlign;

That worked, but whenever I add a new style item, I have to remember to register it here.

So, my problem now is how can I loop over the style and copy every item in there?

With chrome, I managed to do it like this:

```
 var strAttribute = GetDomNameFromAttributeName(oRow.cells[1].style[0]);
    var styletocopy = eval('oRow.cells[1].style.'+strAttribute);
    eval("newCell.style."+strAttribute+"='"+styletocopy+"'"); // //newCell.style.textAlign='center';
```

But that doesn't work with IE. Haven't tested it with FF, but assume chrome compatibiity.

Is there any way to loop over the style elements in IE?
Or is there any better way to copy all style elements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
eval('oRow.cells[1].style.'+strAttribute)
```

Never use `eval` like this(*). In JavaScript you can access a property whose name is stored in a string using square brackets. `object.plop` is the same as `object['plop']`:

```
to.style[name]= from.style[name];
```

(*: never use `eval` at all if you can help it. There are only a few very specific and rare occasions you need it.)

> Is there any way to loop over the style elements

The `style` object is supposed to support the [DOM Level 2 CSS `CSSStyleDeclaration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) interface. You could loop over the rules and apply them to another element like this:

```
for (var i= from.style.length; i-->0;) {
    var name= from.style[i];
    to.style.setProperty(name,
        from.style.getPropertyValue(name),
        priority= from.style.getPropertyPriority(name)
    );
}
```

> in IE?

No, IE does not support the whole CSSStyleDeclaration interface and the above won't work. However there is a simpler way not involving looping that *will* work on IE and the other browsers too:

```
to.style.cssText= from.style.cssText;
```

As simple as that! IE doesn't quite preserve the CSS text the way it should, but the difference doesn't matter for simple inline style copying.

However, as Pikrass said (+1), if you are copying a whole element and not just the styles, `cloneNode` is by far the most elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 9):

You can copy a DOM Element with all its content (including attributes) with .cloneNode(true) :

```
var clonedTr = document.getElementById('id').cloneNode(true);
```

Then clonedTr is an exact copy of the tr #id.
The "true" means you want to copy the content of the element.

Comment: It's just that that doesn't work... besides, I can't get my trs by id, because they don't have one.

Comment: Really ? I just tested, and cloneNode(true) copy the style. The `getElementById('id')` was just for my example, you can access to your element by any method you want (for instance with `table.rows[y].cells[x]`).
If it really doesn't work, you could use a CSS class, it'll be easier than copying every style element.

Comment: cloneNode works fine for me. Whether you get the cell element node by ID or by `oRow.cells[i]` is of no importance.

Comment: It works if you do a appendchild to the tbody. But not if you do insertrow in the middle of a table.

Comment: That's because insertRow creates a new row. It doesn't take your row to put it in the table. You can use insertBefore on your table's tbody instead, like this : `tab.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertBefore(tr, tab.rows[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

To copy all style elements from one node to another you can use

```
newCell.setAttribute('style', oRow.cells[1].getAttribute('style'))
```