# Copy CSS style from one element to a new element in a separate document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I copy CSS style from one element to a new element in a separate document (an IFRAME for instance)?

I've tried to do so by using bobince's answer at [JavaScript & copy style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087778/javascript-copy-style).

Please see my attempt below.

Thank you

http://jsbin.com/uvOFIXIZ/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>copy CSS</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <style type='text/css'>
            .myClass p {font-size:20px;color:blue;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var iframe   = document.createElement('iframe');
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                $(iframe).load(function(){
                    $('.myClass').each(function(){
                        var to=iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
                        console.log(to);
                        var from=this;

                        //Option 1
                        to.style.cssText= from.style.cssText;

                        //Option 2
                        for (var i= from.style.length; i-->0;) {
                            var name= from.style[i];
                            to.style.setProperty(name,
                                from.style.getPropertyValue(name),
                                priority= from.style.getPropertyPriority(name)
                            );
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myClass">
            <p>Stuff!</p>
            <img alt="an image" src="dropdown_arrow_blue.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="myClass">
            <p>More stuff!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT.  Technically, this should work, however, it seems overkill.

```
//Option 3
var arrStyleSheets = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for (var i = 0; i < arrStyleSheets.length; i++){    
    iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(arrStyleSheets[i].cloneNode(true));
}
var arrStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
for (var i = 0; i < arrStyle.length; i++){    
    iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(arrStyle[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: If you can edit the "source" of the styles, move everything into a css class. It's easier to copy a class name to the "target" than individual styles.

Comment: @Cerbrus  And then add an external link to the CSS file in the iframe?  Not ideal, but I suppose possible.  Then do the same thing for any `<style>` tags in the parent?

Comment: Oh, I didn't consider the fact that it'd be an external css file, then.

Comment: @Cerbrus  Even any direct `<style>` tags would need to be copied over, not just the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try what this post refers to -- since you're able to control the src document the iframe uses you can have css class defined in parent then use it in the iframe.  [link to another post on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612374/iframe-inherit-from-parent)

Comment: The iframe is created by the client, so no cross domain issues.  Are you recommending adding all external scripts from the parent to the iframe document?  What if there is a `<style>` element in the parent?  How could this go over?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the stylesheet of the previous document that you want to transfer the css from to your web page and import only what you want using plain css. I usually keep a class file with general properties and setting for various element such as fonts.